# Python regex not giving desired output

Tags: python, regex

I'm scraping a site which contains the following string

```
"1 Year+ in Category"
```

or in some cases

```
"1 Year+ by user in Category
```

I want to separate the Year, Category and the User. I tried using regular split but it doesn't work in this case because there are two delimiters 'in' and 'by'.
So, I used regex. It kinda works but not properly. Here is the snippet

```
dateandcat=re.split(r'.\s[in , by]',rightside[0])
```

rightside[0] contains date,category and user.
It results in the following output:

```
['1 Year', 'n Movies']
['1 Year', 'y user', 'n TV shows']
['1 Year', 'y user', 'n TV shows']
['1 Year', 'n Movies']
```

I could just trim off first two characters in [1] and [2] but I want to fix the regex. Why is second character of 'in' and 'by' still showing? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
import re

value = "1 Year+ in Category by User"

match = re.match(r"(\d+ \w+\+?) in (\w+)(?: by (\w+)*)?", value)
if match:
    print(match.groups())
```

Output:

```
('1 Year+', 'Category', 'User')
```

---

You can use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to learn more about that regex and others.